# Getting input and using it to initialize array works, but according to C , it shouldn't

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, allocation

the code literally gets input from user and allocates is array, and it WORKS in online gdb and geeksforgeeks problem submission?? !?!?!?

```
int n;
int [n];
```

this works!,whereas wherever I've searched, the n inside array should be a constant.

here is the link to the question and the code my friend wrote.

[question](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/card-rotation/0/?category%5B%5D=Queue&problemType=full&page=1&query=category%5B%5DQueueproblemTypefullpage1)

code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int t,n;
    int rear;
    int front;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {

        scanf("%d",&n);
        int a[n],s[n];
        int temp;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            a[i]=i+1;
        front=0;
        rear=n-1;
        
        //rotation
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
            {
                temp=a[front];
                if(front == rear)
                {
                front = -1;
                rear = -1;
                }
                else
                {
                front = (front+1) % n;
                }

                //dequeue
                if(front == -1)
                {
                front = 0;
                }
                rear = (rear + 1) % n;

                a[rear] = temp;
                //enqueue
            }
            temp=a[front];
            if(front == rear)
            {
                front = -1;
                rear = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                front = (front+1) % n;
            }
            s[temp-1]=i;
            //dequeue

        }
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d\t",s[i]);
        printf("\n");
       

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your first snippet is not correct: `int n;int [n];` In this code `n` is not initialized and contains indetermined value. Using it do specify the size of the VLA is undefined behaviour. This is different from the usage in the larger piece of code you show.

Comment: "whereas wherever I've searched, the n inside array should be a constant" - try searching places that are less than 21 years old

Comment: "but according to C , it shouldn't" Says who? Some Brontosaurus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), it was added in `C99`, but `C11` onwards, it's an optional feature.

To quote the standard:

> If the size is not present, the array type is an incomplete type. If the size is `*` instead of being an expression, the array type is a variable length array type of unspecified size, which can only be used in declarations or type names with function prototype scope; such arrays are nonetheless complete types. If the size is an integer constant expression and the element type has a known constant size, the array type is not a variable length array type; **otherwise, the array type is a variable length array type.** (Variable length arrays are a conditional feature that implementations need not support; see 6.10.8.3.)